# can xcode version name include alphabets

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Can   I include alphbets in xcode version

Comment: can you share the compilation error that you are getting?

Comment: I've added a screen shot... it's gives me error for every framework I'm using.

Comment: can you try cleaning the xcode project by cmd+shift+k and quit the xcode. Open xcode and re-run the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try following the below steps

  1. quit Xcode.
  2. pod --version (if its not pls upgrade first).
  3. cd #top level source folder#
  4. pod cache clean —-all
  5. pod deintegrate || rm -rf pods
  6. pod install
  7. launch Xcode and open workspace and compile away.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot  it helped me... And also thanks for for not ignoring..

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
1.Firstly you set the deployment Target 10.3 (**TARGET**,**PROJECT**).
2.Quite Xcode.
3.open terminal cd Project path.
4.open your pod file ---use openpodfile command.
5.copy all pod file in another text file.
6.delete all pod which is written your podfile.
7.pod install.
  after deleting your all pod you are re-paste the pods in podfile.
8.pod install.
 enjoy:).
```