# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) when opening project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have 1 error in realm library when i tryed to import project made with Swift 2.3

[image]

[image]

> ld: library not found for -lrealm-ios
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your derived data?

Comment: i just clean the project and build again, its the same error.

Comment: and how to clean derived data.

Comment: Are you using Dependency manager like cocoapods / carthage for adding the realm library.

Comment: yes i already using cocoapds / cathage for adding the realm @KarthickRamesh.

Comment: @KarthickRamesh what i did u just open the Xcode project and than i clearn project , than build the Project.

Comment: can you add your podfile changes in to the same. Also was the library working fine before and issue happening suddenly?

Comment: Can u contact with me Mr Karthick Remesh.  m.hassan.y1994@gmail.com

Comment: That's not the right way to discuss. If you explain the issue properly here in stack overflow me/someone else can help you. The answer might also help some one else.

Comment: @KarthickRamesh yah i understoody mr Karthick , but i tryed to solve this error for 2 weeks now. didnt got to point.

Comment: Can you please add the codebase in the google drive and add the link in the comments so that i can check the same.

Comment: @KarthickRamesh its private project brother its better to contact directrly through gmail brother.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501139/unable-to-run-my-xcode-9-3-project-in-my-iphone-with-version-10-3-even-after-i-c/50501450#50501450

Comment: @KarthickRamesh problem doest solved.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Preferences > Locations > Derived Data,
Then go to the mentioned derived data folder by clicking the arrow icon.
Clear the data and try again.